# Handling Columns With Multiple Values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table that looks like this:

| id | favorite fruits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apples, bananas |
| 2 | strawberries, bananas |
| 3 | kiwis, apples |

I would like to have each fruit in a different row like so:

| id | favorite fruits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | apples |
| 1 | bananas |
| 2 | strawberries |
| 2 | bananas |
| 3 | kiwis |
| 3 | apples |

Any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Range- go to **Data**- **From Sheet**- open **Power Query editor**- select **favorite fruits** column and under **Home** tab select **Split Column**- Select **By Delimiter**- select **favorite fruits.1** and **favorite fruits.2** columns- go to **Transform**- **Unpivot Columns**- Remove **Attribute** column- change the **Value** name to **favorite fruit**- **Close and load to...**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365, to split the Favorites column on the Comma into Rows.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in the data
//Be sure to change Table Name in next line to the actual name in your workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Fruits"]}[Content],

//set the data type
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"id", Int64.Type}, 
        {"favorite fruits", type text}
        }),

//Split the Favorites column by the comma, into Rows!
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(
        Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {
            {"favorite fruits", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), 
            let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "favorite fruits"),

//Trim the contents of the column to remove leading spaces (when delimiter was <comma> <space>
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"favorite fruits", Text.Trim, type text}})
in
    #"Trimmed Text"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much